# Render MVC View layout from database with Razor Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

As per requirement, i need to retrieve html page layout from database (that system user can update through system) with some html helpers (Dropdown, TextBox etc).

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    @Html.DropDown(x=>x.SomeId,Model.ElementCollection)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Property)
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example, i need to get html from database but before render the page i want added some html helper's.So it will work like formal page.

**Tried Solution:**
For this i have created Custom View Engine and i am replacing text into *Render* function of IView inherited class.but its not resolving html from helper.

**Question:**

Is there any to get html from htmlHelper.If yes, then i can simply replace string into action method and return Content from action method?

Suggest please.

Comment: Do you need to use the form to post data to some action or only for viewing purpose ?

Comment: Yes @serene, i am using two-way binding helper in above example. i googed lot i found some helpful link : [link1](http://blog.rocketbase.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-virtual-path-provider/) and [link2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1705855.aspx?Storing+Razor+view+in+the+database)

Answer (score 0):

I found some useful link, to implement same functionality with Custom View Engine and Virtual Views.

[Link1](http://blog.rocketbase.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-virtual-path-provider/) And [Link2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1705855.aspx?Storing%20Razor%20view%20in%20the%20database)

Thanks :)